# ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::DataCorrupted: ERROR

Tags: postgresql

This is the full error message

ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::DataCorrupted: ERROR:  could not read block 0 in file "base/50711/50722": read only 0 of 8192 bytes

What could be the root cause of this?

Answer (score 0):

The error report from md.c. I think your block corrupted. your filesystem setting or block device's setting not strong?
you can set zero_damaged_pages skip this block.

```
if (nbytes != BLCKSZ)
{
        if (nbytes < 0)
                ereport(ERROR,
                                (errcode_for_file_access(),
                                 errmsg("could not read block %u in file \"%s\": %m",
                                                blocknum, FilePathName(v->mdfd_vfd))));

        /*
         * Short read: we are at or past EOF, or we read a partial block at
         * EOF.  Normally this is an error; upper levels should never try to
         * read a nonexistent block.  However, if zero_damaged_pages is ON or
         * we are InRecovery, we should instead return zeroes without
         * complaining.  This allows, for example, the case of trying to
         * update a block that was later truncated away.
         */
        if (zero_damaged_pages || InRecovery)
                MemSet(buffer, 0, BLCKSZ);
        else
                ereport(ERROR,
                                (errcode(ERRCODE_DATA_CORRUPTED),
                                 errmsg("could not read block %u in file \"%s\": read only %d of %d bytes",
                                                blocknum, FilePathName(v->mdfd_vfd),
                                                nbytes, BLCKSZ)));
}
```